# A Poisson process with a fixed maximum number of counts?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

For a Poisson process, we have the pmf of arrival in (0,t] as:
$$p(n)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n \exp(-\lambda t)}{n!}$$
where $\lambda$ is the arrival rate and the PDF of the inter-arrival times is given as:
$$f(t)=\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$$
What if I assume that the maximum number of counts that is possible is $N$, I mean in case of a call scenario the maximum calls can never exceed beyond say $N$. For such a scenario:
$\sum_{n=1}^{500}p(n)=1$ and $\sum_{n=501}^{600}p(n)=0$. Can w incorporate such a scenario in the Poisson processes?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then I believe such a distribution is possible. Your original probability mass function was defined by
$$P(n\text{ arrivals in }(0,t])=p(n)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!}$$

If you wish to limit the “number of arrivals” to $N$, then the new probability mass function will be given by the following, for $n\le N$:
$$\begin{align}P(n\text{ arrivals in }(0,t] \space | \text{ at most N arrivals})&=\frac{P(n\text{ arrivals in }(0,t])}{P(\text{at most N arrivals})}\\
&= \frac{p(n)}{\sum_{k=0}^N p(k)}\\
 \end{align}$$
Which should give the distribution you are looking for.

Comment: Please note that the counting process is Poisson process when the inter-arrival rate is exponential $f(t)=\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$, now if the number of counts is limited but still the inter-arrival rate is exponential, can we replace the counting process by the distribution that you suggested?

Comment: No. The inter-arrival rate can no longer be exponential, and in fact, the inter-arrival rates for each arrival are not even independent any more. Since there can be at most $N$ arrivals, a shorter arrival time for one event implies that the others must take longer to arrive in order to last until time $t$ without more than $N$ arrivals.

Comment: I have a doubt here about the decaying of a radioactive particle. The particle survives for time $t$ before decaying is given by an exponential distribution(source wiki) and particle decay is a Poisson process.  If I assume a certain number of particle present initially and as a rule number of particles decay can't be more than the total particles initially present. How is particle decay a Poisson process?